# Node Js Async Await giving first response Empty

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am New To async/await coding in node js. I am trying to fetch data from mongodb and then populate the result into an object. But I am facing a bizarre issue here when I exit the server and turn it back on and then hit the API in node js the first response is always empty. I start getting the response as soon as I hit the API after 1st attempt below is my code

```
let resu={};

router.get('/getTarrifDetails',async (req,res,next) => {
  await Tarrif.find().distinct('tarrif_type',(err,docs) => {
    docs.forEach(async (ele) => {
      let count= User.countDocuments({tarrif_type:ele});
      result.push(ele);
      result[ele] = await count;
      result.push(count);
    });
  });

  getAll(res);
});

async function getAll(res) {
  if(await resu.length!=0) {
    res.send(resu);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't mean this in an insulting way but you don't seem to have a good idea on what you're doing here. There are many weird things you're doing wrong,  solving async issues should be the least of your worries.

Comment: @NikKyriakides as You understood that experienced developer will have idea what he/she do. So just explain him how to solve and why. Give some links to learn things.

Comment: @num8er Your answer covered it pretty good. I'm just pointing out that the OP might wanna brush up a bit more on the basics.

Comment: @BensonOO please take a look at this example repository to see a bit of best practices: https://github.com/num8er/TokenAuthTest

Comment: Thank You @num8er For the help i m new to node.js development thats why i am facing such issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong.

1) It's not recommended to store contextual variable `resu` outside of request scope.

2) `result.push` ? where is `result` variable? out of scope again?

3) `resu.length` ? it's not an array, it's an object, so You'll not get `false` or `0` result.

4) `find().distinct('tarrif_type', (err,docs) => ...` mongoose supports promises, so why You used it with callback?

5) `await resu.length` ? it's not a promise, it's just an object and length is property, You cannot ask `await` from non-promise attribute

6) `getAll` what if `resu.length` really will have `0`? what it will respond? - so request will hang, so You've to respond anything to gracefully close connection created during request.

So overall fix should work:

```
router.get('/getTarrifDetails', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tarrifTypes = await Tarrif.find().distinct('tarrif_type');

    const tarrifCounters = {};
    let total = 0;
    for(const tarrifType of tarrifTypes) {
      const count = await User.count({tarrif_type: tarrifType});
      tarrifCounters[tarrifType] = count;
      total+= count;
    }

    res.status(200).send({
      tarrifTypes,
      tarrifCounters,
      total
    });
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

or using parallelism:

```
const getTarrifUsersCounters = async (tarrifTypes) => {
  // initial result
  const result = {
    tarrifTypes,
    tarrifCounters: {},
    total: 0
  };

  // if no tarriffTypes passed return result
  if (!(Array.isArray(tarrifTypes) && tarrifTypes.length > 0)) {
   return result;
  }

  // generating array of promises from tarrifTypes
  const callStack = [];
  for(const tarrifType of tarrifTypes) {
    callStack.push(
      new Promise(async resolve => {
        const count = await User.count({tarrif_type: tarrifType});
        resolve({tarrifType, count});
      });
    );
  }

  // calling promises array in parallel
  if (callStack.length) {
    (await Promise.all(callStack))
      .forEach(
        ({tarrifType, count}) => {
          result.tarrifCounters[tarrifType] = count;
          result.total += count;
        });
  }

  return result;
};

router.get('/getTarrifDetails', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tarrifTypes = await Tarrif.find().distinct('tarrif_type');
    const result = await getTarrifUsersCounters(tarrifTypes);
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } 
  catch(error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks alot sir I am new to node js development.Your explanation sure cleared alot of ambiguities  in my mind

Comment: @BensonOO happy to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the **await** statement is finished before you can compare.
Remember that **async/await** does not make the code run in sync, it just formats it in a way for us developers to appear like it is sync.

```
function findData() {
      return Tarrif.find().distinct('tarrif_type',(err,docs)=>{
          docs.forEach(async (ele)=>{
          let count= User.countDocuments({tarrif_type:ele});
          result.push(ele);
          resu[ele]=await count;
          result.push(count);
        });
      });
    };


router.get('/getTarrifDetails',async (req,res,next)=>{
    let res = null;
    try {
       res = await findData();
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    if(res !== 0){
      //do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }

});
```